# How can you use variables when defining xrange in gnuplot?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnuplot

I wrote a script in Bash, and I want to plot data with gnuplot. When I call this script with gnuplot, the error message is:

```
"sar-P-gnuplot-script", line 3: Column number or datablock line expected
```

It seems that you're unable to define any variables when doing:

```
gnuplot "*my_script*"
```

Code/Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

current_time=$(date +"%T")
new_time=$(date -d "$current_time today + 10 seconds" +'%H:%M:%S')

set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["$current_time":"$new_time"]
set format x "%H:%M:%S"
plot "sar-P-plots11" using 1:2
pause -1 "Hit any key to continue"
```

Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# sar-P-script : script that will take sar-P and plot it

current_t=$(date +"%T")

# input the sar-P results into a file
sar -P 1 1 11 > sar-P-1-1-11

new_t=$(date +"%T")

# remove the first line (you don't need it)
sed -i '/dennis/d' sar-P-1-1-11

# makes the spaces commas, and then squeezes repeating commas
tr -s  ' ' ',' < sar-P-1-1-11 > new-sar-P-1-1-11

# cuts the first field into a new file (the times)
cut -d ',' -f 1 new-sar-P-1-1-11 > sar-times11

# cuts the last field into a new file (percentages)
cut -d ',' -f 8 new-sar-P-1-1-11 > sar-idle11

# creates an x and y table
paste sar-times11 sar-idle11 > sar-P-plots11

# cuts away anything that we don't need (headers)
sed -i '/Average/d' sar-P-plots11
sed -i '/idle/d' sar-P-plots11

./sar-P-gnuplot-script
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Error**:

```
current_time=$(date +"%T")
new_time=$(date -d "10 seconds" +'%H:%M:%S')
```

current_time needs to be declared before running sar-P, and
new_time needs to be declared after running sar-P

**Second Error**:

```
gnuplot <<EOF
```

needs to be

```
gnuplot -p <<EOF
```

This is to ensure that the plot will persist after the gnuplot function executes.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up `bash` and `gnuplot`. The first two lines look like `bash` and the rest looks like `gnuplot`, so you probably want something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

current_time=$(date +"%T")
new_time=$(date -d "10 seconds" +'%H:%M:%S')

# Start "gnuplot" passing in some "bash" variables
gnuplot <<EOF
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["$current_time":"$new_time"]
set format x "%H:%M:%S"
plot "sar-P-plots11" using 1:2
pause -1 "Hit any key to continue"
EOF
```

Save the script as `plotit`, then make it executable with:

```
chmod +x plotit
```

and then run it with:

```
./plotit
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Mark! Say I wanted to execute this inside of another script. Would I just reference it in the script? Because when I tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. You can copy all the stuff from `current_time=$(date +"%T")` to `EOF` and paste all that into another `bash` script, if that's what you mean.

Comment: When I ran it the way you told me to, I got "line 0: warning: Bad time format in string." I have one script that takes the output from the sar-P command, and then I format it to what I want. Inside of that script, I would wish to call this script that will take the new nice data and graph it with gnuplot.

Comment: What's very interesting is that everything is formatted correctly, and the only issue here is using variables instead of hard-coded times. The reason I want to use these variables here is because I don't want to hard-code the specific time range when I gather my data each time I run my script.

Comment: Your original line starting `new_time=...` seems wrong. I have updated it in the answer.

Comment: I realized one of my issues a minute ago. I needed to declare the current_time right before I gather data, and the new_time once I gathered the data... What's left to be answered is why I get this error: "line 0: warning: Bad time format in string. line 0: Can't plot with an empty x range!" I'll put in my other script that I use to take in data.

Comment: It seems that now gnuplot runs but for a split second. I thought that the pause -1 "Hit any key to continue " command would override this.